# глобальная переменная равна undefined после присвоения ей значения

Tags: typescript, angular

Есть три переменные. Все глобальные.

```
first = 0;
second = 0;
third = 0;
// Выводя в консоль все три переменные имеют значение
```

Использую одно событие на DOM элементе - `onmousedown`. В нём задаю значения этим переменным

```
this.first = 1;
this.second = 2;
this.third = 3;
```

плюсом к этому здесь же задаю `document.onmousemove` функцию, в которой используются эти глобальные переменные.

```
document.onmousemove = foo();

foo (){
    console.log(this.first);
    console.log(this.second);
    console.log(this.third);
}
```

все переменные `undefined`.
Может кто-нибудь объяснить причину такого поведения?

Comment: Попробуйте убрать ключевое слово `this`. Возможно, из-за него контекст ограничивается функцией `foo()`.

Comment: @Marionette, пробовал. В таком случае typescript не знает куда ему обращаться за этими переменными

Comment: Добавьте `let` перед названием переменной при объявлении.

Comment: @Marionette, глобальная переменная в компоненте не может быть так объявлена. Пробовал сделать её public и private но результат тот же

Comment: @eriksongerson а что ты вообще пытаешься сделать? `document.onmousemove = foo()` ты просто присваиваешь значение `undefined`, и все. Если ты хочешь назначить функцию, которая будет выполняться при файринге события `mousemove`, то тебе нужно присваивать саму функцию с биндингом контекста - `document.onmousemove = this.foo.bind(this)`. Если без `bind`, то `document.onmousemove = this.foo`, но при этом `foo` нужно заменить на стрелочную функцию - `foo = () => { console.log(this.first); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя проблема заключалась в том, что когда я задаю

```
document.onmousemove = foo();

foo (){
    console.log(this.first);
    console.log(this.second);
    console.log(this.third);
}
```

функция foo() находится внутри компонента

```
export class SomeComponent {

    first = 0;
    second = 0;
    third = 0;

    someFunction(){
        ...
        this.first = 1;
        this.second = 2;
        this.third = 3;      
        document.onmousemove = this.foo();
        ...
    }

    foo(){
        console.log(this.first);
        console.log(this.second);
        console.log(this.third);
    }

}
```

Если бы я сделал иначе, всё заработало бы с первой попытки:

```
export class SomeComponent {

    first = 0;
    second = 0;
    third = 0;

    someFunction(){
        ...
        this.first = 1;
        this.second = 2;
        this.third = 3;      
        document.onmousemove = this.foo();
        ...
        // С тем же успехом можно было бы задать лямбда-функцию
        let foo = () => {
            console.log(this.first);
            console.log(this.second);
            console.log(this.third);
        }
    }    
}
```